# TeXShop console freezes when compiling large files (intermittent)

Tags: compiling, texshop

About once out of every four times that I compile a large LaTeX project (about 780 pages) in TeXShop, the console freezes and stops the compiling.  The content of the LaTeX files does not seem to affect the freezing--I can compile exactly the same file 2-3 times in a row with no problem and then the next time or two it freezes, and then I can compile it again a few more times. Where it freezes in the document also seems random--sometimes on page 200, another time on page 779.

There is no error thrown, no warning, nothing--it just stops compiling and waits.  The console also does not accept further input at that point.  But the rest of TeXShop still continues to work fine, so to recover I just have to recompile (twice, since the aux files are all damaged by this).  Since the project is big, compiling takes a while, so this is a bother.

I am running TeXShop version Version 4.21 on a 2015 MacBook Air 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, with 8GB RAM running Mojave (10.14).  But I have had this problem for several months, running earlier versions of MacOS and earlier versions of TeXShop.  This also happens on my 2013 iMac, 3.5 GHz Intel Core i7, with 24GB RAM, also running Mojave, but also occured on previous versions of MacOS and previous versions of TeXShop.

The command that TeXShop runs to compile is

```
pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 book.tex
```

The problem has not yet occurred in the mac terminal when I run the same pdflatex command there (with TeXShop still up and running), so I don't think it is a TeX problem or memory issue.

I would be grateful for any ideas anyone might have for fixing this.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This has been discussed on this page https://tug.org/pipermail/texshop/2018-December/date.html. Unfortunately, the cause seems to remain a mystery. I have experienced this myself. Annoying, but there seems to be no lasting damage.

Comment: The key word is `intrmittent`. This has made it difficult to analyze.

Comment: Please see my comment to the ``answer''  below. Basically, are you using, even only occasionally, anti-virus software like MalwareBytes or bitDefender?

Comment: @HerbSchulz: I have experienced a similar issue with smaller files as well, so don't think it is at all related to the size of the file being compiled. And I am _not_ running any anti-virus softare. However, I am running in a Dropbox monitored folder but don't think that is the cause of the issue.  I haven't bothered to report is as I have not been able to determine a method to duplicate the issue.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: Although this problem seems to be not be a TeXShop issue, I have _not_ noticed a similar issue when I run with pdflatex from the command line. The files I process via command line (outside of TeXShop) are different files, so can't totaly rule out it being just a `pdflatex` issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill : my very occasional experiences with the problem are with much smaller files too. It might very well be true that the probability of it happening gets higher the longer the processing goes on.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: My external pdflatex takes about 30 minutes (on a 2013 Macbook Pro i7 with 16GB) to produce an approx. 6000 page document. I run this every night and it has _never_ frozen on me. BTW, I am using TeXShop V 4.21.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I have heard of compile problems when typesetting files in a DropBox.Best practice is to temporarily turn off updating before a typesetting session and turn it back on when done so there is no chance of interference between updating and file changes.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I am not using and have not installed any antivirus software.  The file being compiled does live in a Dropbox file.  I am not convinced this is a problem with tex instead of TeXShop--I never get this problem when running the exact same command in the same directory from the Mac terminal--only in the TeXShop console.

Comment: @TylerJarvis : other software that use NSTask have reports of the problem so it isn’t  TeXShop alone that is experiencing it.

Comment: I have been seeing this same issue for months, through several updates of TeXShop, including now V4.27.  I am not running in Dropbox. Mac OS 10.14.5. Is there any fix yet?

Comment: @John According to Herb Schulz this is a problem with NSTask and not just TeXShop.  For now my workaround is just to compile in the terminal, which is a little bit of a hassle, because TeXShop doesn't display the new pdf until I close the document in TeXShop and then reopen it.

Comment: @TylerJarvis  Thanks, Tyler.  I just read through the discussion forum linked in an earlier comment and looked at the changelog for TexShop.  It appears that this problem has been considered to be resolved since January or so.... I will see if I can post question directly into the TexShop forum.

Comment: BTW, a promising update on this issue has just appeared on the [mailing list](https://tug.org/pipermail/texshop/2019-August/000140.html).  Meanwhile, Tyler's command-line approach (above) has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been an update of TeXShop to version 4.35. This version should fix your problem. You can either update using the `TeXShop->Check for Updates…` menu item or go directly to https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/texshop.html and download it from there.

Comment: I have not seen the problem occur since I installed the update.  Thanks for fixing this!

Answer (score 1):

I have had very similar problems using TeXShop to format an 800-page book.  I use a new MacBook Pro.  These time-consuming problems began to occur when I "upgraded" from High Sierra to Mojave.

The problem is deeper than TeXShop.  It is TeX itself that is halting.  So switching to a different latex editor does not help.

One could use AppDelete to remove MalwareBytes and other apps that might be interfering with TeX/Mojave.  I first deleted MalwareBytes and then downloaded AppDelete, and now I can't get AppDelete to find MalwareBytes so as to remove its unwanted remnants.

Comment: There have been some comments about a problem with NSTask, in another piece of software, when MalwareBytes or BitDefender (or other anti-virus software?) has been used. Are you using, or have used, either of those items?

Comment: With respect, this seems more a *question* or *comment* than an *answer*. Still, in an attempt to help, I can suggest three: TeXnicle, Texpad ($$) and texstudio. Be warned: none of these is anywhere near as polished and easy to use as TeXShop. TeXShop, from the beginning, has been the gold standard for TeX editors IMO (on the Mac, anyway). Hopefully this glitch is a passing annoyance. There is always emacs and AUCTeX, though this is **FAR** from a straightforward way to go.

Comment: MalwareBytes has a built-in un-install under its Help menu. How can AppDelete determine files to delete if you delete the main file first? Try re-installing MalwareBytes and either use AppDelete or the built-in un-install to clean up everything. Then re-boot to make sure any helper apps are no longer started up.

Comment: Please try the latest version of TeXShop, 4.22, which attempts to get around the problem.

Comment: I see this same issue with large documents in Version 4.27 (and early ones).  Is there a fix as of yet?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Sadly, I am still seeing the problem while using TexShop 4.31.   For short documents I get some freezing, but it isn't a big deal, because I can just compile again.  But my 800-page book takes so long to compile that there is too much time lost when it freezes on page 750.  So for large documents I compile from the regular terminal, which is still my best workaround (but not nearly as convenient as TeXShop, when it doesn't freeze).

Comment: @TylerJarvis : There are the beginnings of an ability to understand what is happening but certainly not in detail. You could use the \batchmode command at the start of your file to reduce the probability of a problem. This will essentially tell (pdf/xe/lua)latex to silence almost all Console output. All the information will still be in the log file. If you use TeXShop's (pdf/xe/lua)latexmk engine you could use the TeXShop directive `% !TEX parameter = --interaction=batchmode` to accomplish the same thing as the \batchmode command.

Comment: @TylerJarvis : I believe there will be an update to TeXShop that finally solves the problem! :-)

Comment: I am testing and until now it works. It doesn't freeze with a very long reledmac file.