# On large files, TeXShop halts intermittently on Mojave

Tags: texshop

I use TeXShop, but TeXShop halts intermittently on Mojave, so I am looking for a latex editor that works consistently on Mojave. Apple won't look for the bugs in Mojave that cause TeXShop to halt. I wish I had stayed with High Sierra. I'm looking for an alternative to TeXShop that works better on Mojave.

Comment: This is a known problem with, thus far, no solution. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466714/texshop-console-freezes-when-compiling-large-files-intermittent?r=SearchResults